# Packages in DB2

Tags: oracle, db2, package, sql-pl

I'm wondering if there is a package construct in DB2 like in Oracle.

For DB2 I found [stored procedures and functions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0053914.html).

In Oracle one could group several stored procedures and functions together in a package. Is there something similar in DB2? I know one can enable some Oracle compatibility, however we should be using IBM stuff here.

I found an older article on [DB2 packages](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0606chun/index.html) however this seems to relate to a totally different concept. It seems to be more about integrating third party libraries and doing the coding outside of the database with different programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 has [modules](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053759.html), which are equivalent to Oracle packages.

When using Oracle compatibility within DB2, the `CREATE PACKAGE` statement DB2 will create a module.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are packages in DB2.

Here's a link to the IBM manual section on [packages](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0053911.html).

Here's a link to the IBM manual section on IBM's [SQL procedural language](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0011916.html), which you can use in SQL procedures.

Comment: This are Oracle PL/SQL packages where DB2 is emulating an Oracle DB. That is what I ment with "Oracle compatibility".

Comment: @Udo Held: The DB2 link you provided in your question pointed to the PL/SQL section of the IBM manual.  That's why I assumed you could use IBM's PL/SQL.  I've added a link to IBM's SQL procedural language in my answer.